# How to use svg.js's transform with matrix parameter in typescript?

Tags: typescript, svg, matrix, svg.js

When I use svg.js lib with javascript, I can transform a given element via a `SVG.Matrix` like so:

```
import * as SVG from 'svg.js';

let draw = SVG('drawing').size(200, 200);
let rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' });
rect.translate(100,100);
let matrix = new SVG.Matrix(rect);
let rect2 = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f60' });
rect2.transform(matrix);
```

In the example the 2nd rect gets transformed like the first rect via `SVG.Matrix`:

```html
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1001" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs"><defs id="SvgjsDefs1002"></defs><rect id="SvgjsRect1008" width="100" height="100" fill="#ff0066" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,100,100)"></rect><rect id="SvgjsRect1009" width="100" height="100" fill="#ff6600" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,100,100)"></rect></svg>
```

However the same code in typescript claims:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'Matrix' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Transform'.
  Types of property 'skewX' are incompatible.
    Type '(x: number, cx?: number, cy?: number) => Matrix' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

How can I transform an element via a `SVG.Matrix` in typescript?
Why does `svgjs.Element.transform` behave different when used with ts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svg.js.d.ts` tells that `Element.transform` has this [signature](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/blob/5a72b487125beaa6b7bd81584fb9d35c4ffc43be/svg.js.d.ts#L902):

```
interface Element {
    transform(t: Transform, relative?: boolean): Element;
    transform(): Transform;
    ...
}
```

So, this should work:

```
const transform = rect.transform();
let rect2 = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f60' });
rect2.transform(transform);
```

Essentially, both `Transform` and `Matrix` objects have a/b/c/d/e/f properties, so in Javascript one can be used in place of the other, but in Typescript, they have no prototypical relation and the compiler complains.

It's actually a bug in the typings. Looking at the source code, the transformation is implemented by [calling](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/blob/5a72b487125beaa6b7bd81584fb9d35c4ffc43be/src/transform.js#L128) `new Matrix(t)`, so the signature to `.transform()` should read:

```
transform(t: MatrixAlias, relative?: boolean): Element;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. It does work for the example I gave, but my real usecase would be to apply multiplied matrices to elements.
SVG.Transform has a matrix-method – but I'm still left with the problem of applying the matrix… SVG.Transform does not offer a multiply-method as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I think yes, it would be. Maybe even a good opportunity for me to gain further ts knowledge :)

Comment: Works :) I'll file an issue and pull request on https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js (?)

Comment: @ccprog We are aware that our typings are not comlete. However, we are lacking the knowledge and time to complete / correct them. Feel free, to open a PR with fixes. Every bit helps!